# Using contains to compare references in generic arraylist

Tags: java, generics, collections, arraylist, contains

Ok so I'm trying to compare references in a generic arraylist.

```
for (int s=0; s<orders.size(); s++) {
  if (orders.get(s).contains(cpCollection.get(m)))
    System.out.println(orders.get(s).getSerial());
}
```

I'm getting an error message that it can not find symbol for the contains method.
I think I need to mention that its not a normal arraylist however. Here is some more code.

Orders is this

```
ArrayList<GenericOrder<Product>> orders = new ArrayList<GenericOrder<Product>>();
```

The class name is GenericOrder. Here is the code from the beginning of the file to clear some other things up.

```
public class GenericOrder<T> {
private ArrayList<T> products;
public GenericOrder() {
products = new ArrayList<T>();
}
}
```

So basically I need to compare array refences so I can check if a Product which is an object is located inside the orders arraylist, which is a GenericOrder arraylist.
If the contains returns true then I want to print that orders serial number which is a method getSerial. This method works fine if I were to say orders.get(1).getSerial(); This would return "Order: 1".

I hope this makes sense. I can publish the entire code if needed but I would like to avoid that since its university homework and I dont want someone stealing the entire thing.

Thanks muchly.

Comment: Compiler said that GenericOrder doesn't have contains method. Just implement it. Btw, what is cpCollection?

Comment: cpCollection is another type of arraylist. It contains products that are ComputerParts. (computerparts inherit from products).

Answer (score 2):

As MAKKAM says in the comments, this is failing:

```
GenericOrder<Product> order = orders.get(s);
order.contains( ... ) // Doesn't compile
```

The GenericOrder class does not have a contains() method.

Your two solutions are either to expose the internal list:

```
order.getProducts().contains( ... ); // Will work
```

or implement a contains() method:

```
public class GenericOrder<T> {
  private ArrayList<T> products;

  public boolean contains(T t) {
    return products.contains(t);
  }
}
```

Comment: I attempted to implement contains while I was waiting for a response. For some reason, it returns true for both my collections. I have created a compOrder array and compPartyOrder array. The computerparts im testing for have been added to the compOrder but not the other one but it somehow returns true for both. I used your contains method instead of the one I tried but its the same result. I will check back in the morning. Thanks very much guys.

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being a `HashMap`. its not perfect but it works.
The `HashMap` associates each product object (they key) with the order number (the value). I couldn't get it to associate with the serialNo, it would always set to 5 and it really wasnt' worth the effort trying to get it 100%.
It works though because it loops through orders, from 0 to order.size() and it just so happens that when orders are created, they are numbered from 0 on. So the numbers line up as long as the serialNo structure or initialized variable doesn't change. I'll probably lose a few marks for it but honestly at this point, i just want it done.